# formatcurrency Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

Team, I'm trying to format a string of characters into Italian Currency format - say something like €1.230,32 from the api documentation i understand it can be achieved through [Worklight](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/dev/c_globalization_in_ibm_worklight.html) - [Corodova](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/cordova_globalization_globalization.md.html#globalization.getCurrencyPattern). But I'm not able to land in a clear - cut example as to how. Can you help ?

Comment: What is the string of characters you're trying to format, from what to what? Lets be exact.

Comment: The string of characters can be 123556456.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear to me.

If what you actually want to do is to convert a sum of money from one currency to another, you can check the following:

- http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_globalization_globalization.md.html
- https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization/blob/master/docs/globalization.getCurrencyPattern.md
- http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdev%2Fc_globalization_in_ibm_worklight.html
- http://www.sitepoint.com/build-a-currency-converter-with-jquery-mobile-and-cordova-part-4/

Comment: I'll get a series of characters from the webservice which shall be like 12345552.00 My funtion should use some corodova / worklight API and convert the input characters to the Italian Currency Format €1.23.45.552,00

Comment: It's all about putting in some comma and dots

Comment: You have this Cordova API: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_globalization_globalization.md.html#globalization.getCurrencyPattern